# What's the correct way to create a YAML document without a file?

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

I want to create a YAML file from scratch inside a python program (with PyYAML), to send it inside a HTTP request body. The closest thing I've found in the [PyYAML docs](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation) is this:

```
import yaml
document = """
  a: 1
  b:
    c: 3
    d: 4
"""
yaml.load(document)
send_req(document)
```

However, I find it *ugly* and not very maintainable, so I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
document = {'a': 1, 'b': {'c': 3, 'd': 4}}
yaml.load(document)
send_req(document)
```

So I can modify its structure in a programmatic way, with variables and so.

How can I create a YAML document from a python object structure?

Comment: You have your terminology all mixed up and that is why you probably couldn't Google an answer for this yourself. You never `load` a YAML **structure**. You `load` a YAML document (from a file or a string). You instead have a Python data structure that you want to represent as a YAML document. You do that by  `dump`-ing it to a stream using `safe_dump(document, stream)`.  Apart from that you better use `safe_load()` instead of `load()`, since PyYAML's `load()` is unsafe. To answer your question: yes, that is possible.

Comment: @Anthon have you considered turning your useful comment into an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is [`yaml.dump`](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation#DumpingYAML).

```
document = {'a': 1, 'b': {'c': 3, 'd': 4}}
print(yaml.dump(document))
>>> a: 1
b: {c: 3, d: 4}
```

For simple Python objects you can even serialize [`.__dict__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#object.__dict__) directly:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

my_obj = MyClass(1, 2)
print(yaml.dump(my_obj.__dict__))
>>> {a: 1, b: 2}
```

Comment: So should I do something like `myyaml= yaml.dump(document)` ? And then, `yaml.load(myyaml)` ?

Comment: @agsergi Yes, the output of `yaml.dump` can be used directly as input of `yaml.load`.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.